# interpretting output from keras model predict

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, predict

Any tutorials or example i find are about interpreting output are always about keras model.predict classification. ie the answer is from 0 to 1 and that represents probability of belonging to 1 class or another.

i am passing in this very small amount of data

```
time_list = [1296000.0, 19350000.0, 29635200.0, 48294000.0, 45961200.0]
tax_list = [0.1, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.6]
price_list = [0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0]
```

and then ultimately get this output

```
 [[-0.34306246] ## prediction output 
 [-0.34306246]
 [-0.34306246]
 [-0.34306246]
 [-0.34306246]]
```

Is this a prediction of a future price or an attempt at classification? how can i even tell? it seems unreasonable for either.

full source code

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
tf.random.set_seed(0)
# sample data
time_list = [1296000.0, 19350000.0, 29635200.0, 48294000.0, 45961200.0]
tax_list = [0.1, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.6]
price_list = [0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 0.0, 0.1]
# generate the feature matrix
X = np.hstack([np.array(time_list).reshape(- 1, 1), np.array(tax_list).reshape(- 1, 1)])
print(X.shape)
# (5, 2)
# generate the target array
Y = np.array(price_list)
print(Y.shape)
# (5,)
# reshape the features
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1])
print(X.shape)
# (5, 1, 2)
# define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences=False, input_shape=( 1 , len(X[0][0]))))
model.add(Dense(1))
# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=1, epochs=10)
# generate the model predictions
pred = model.predict(X)
print(pred)
```

i suspect the honest answer is probably "the correct interpretation of this is you started with some number , the computer added more numbers to it and now you've merely got new numbers." but what was the intention at least? was it trying to organize things into classes or predict a new price on a different day or something else?

This confuses me as i provide no classes for the model to consider nor do i provide a future date to predict for so what could it be?

Comment: Your model is configured to do regression, so it is just approximating whatever label y you trained with.

Comment: so in leymans terms you're saying its trying to do a "best fit line" to predict future prices and taxes? but on what date would it be predicting for?

Comment: You keep asking about "dates" and we have no idea about that, it depends on to which "date" your labels y correspond. The model is not doing any magic, it is doing exactly what you trained it for.

Comment: sorry, the time_list is a list of dates.
so if its "approximating" my features, are we saying it is somehow 
 taking the average of my features?

Comment: No, I am talking about Y, the model is not averaging the features.

Comment: ok so do you mean its trying to average y. or do you mean something else by approximating like predicting or...

Comment: Why do you keep asking about some averaging? I have never mentioned any averaging, your model seems to be poorly trained, it is a linear model too.

Comment: im just trying to work out what you meant by approximate.

Comment: Approximating means minimizing the mean squared error (your loss). But also I am not sure if you trained your model correctly until convergence.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the price (your target) does not imply that you're interested in a classification task. In order to set up a proper classification task, you provide 0-1 labels (assuming binary classification) and typically you throw in a softmax function in your output layer. Softmax converts the output to probability estimates. So, assuming that you convert your price values to 0 for class A and 1 for class B, you'd train your model with a softmax output function and get these score estimates. [Here's how dense layer works.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense) Use `'activation' = 'softmax'`

Also, the reason why you got the same number for every input is because the values of the so called dates are extremely difficult to handle. NNs love inputs around 0 for many reasons and the default tensorflow weights are struggling with your input. Consider scaling it [using this or any other scaler.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)